# Displaying OpenOffice Base data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, openoffice-base

Is this possible?  I assume I need an ODBC driver or other recognised from Excel/Query to access Base.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, at least not easily. OO Base is a front end that actually uses [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) as its database engine. There is [this](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=760) thread in the OO community forum where a workaround is proposed to unzip your .odb file and use JDBC to connect to the HSQLDB database. (I haven't tried this). The OO forum thread is a bit old, so it might be a good idea to try to find alternatives.